# What was debate between Sri karpatri maharaja and Sri vidyamanya tirtha?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, dvaita

What was debate between Sri karpatri maharaja and Sri vidyamanya tirtha?
What was dialogues between them?
By which argument Sri karpatri maharaja win the debate ?